# Understanding the Difference Between 'Usually' and 'Sometimes'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, adverbs, sentence

As an English learner, I often find myself confused about the correct usage of certain adverbs, especially when they seem to have similar meanings. I'm particularly unsure about the difference between "usually" and "sometimes."

Could someone explain how these two adverbs differ in meaning and usage? In what contexts is it appropriate to use "usually" as opposed to "sometimes"?

Comment: Please edit to show that you've looked up "usually" and "sometimes" in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Usually" implies that the thing happens more often than not, whereas "sometimes" suggests a more occasional occurrence.

*"I usually go the cinema on a Friday evening. Sometimes, I go a restaurant instead"*